# "Value does not fall within the expected range," when writing to Workbook.CustomDocumentProperties

Tags: c#, excel, ms-office, office-interop, com-interop

A simple assignment like the one below from a console application written in C#:

```
workbook.CustomDocumentProperties.Item["PropertyName"] = "Property Value";
```

Produces the following error:

```
{"Value does not fall within the expected range."}
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    HResult: -2147024809
    HelpLink: null
    IPForWatsonBuckets: 0x633f1015
    InnerException: null
    IsTransient: false
    Message: "Value does not fall within the expected range."
    ParamName: null
    RemoteStackTrace: null
    Source: "System.Dynamic"
    StackTrace: "   at System.Dynamic.ComRuntimeHelpers.CheckThrowException(Int32 hresult, ExcepInfo& excepInfo, UInt32 argErr, String message)\r\n   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , String , Object )\r\n   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute3[T0,T1,T2,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)\r\n   at CustomDocumentProperties.Program.WriteToExcelCustomDocumentProperties(String excelFile, String outputFolder, String propertyName, Object propertyValue) in C:\\Sathyaish\\DotNet\\CustomDocumentProperties\\CustomDocumentProperties\\Program.cs:line 100"
    TargetSite: {Void CheckThrowException(Int32, System.Dynamic.ExcepInfo ByRef, UInt32, System.String)}
    WatsonBuckets: null
    _HResult: -2147024809
    _className: null
    _data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    _dynamicMethods: {object[2]}
    _exceptionMethod: {Void CheckThrowException(Int32, System.Dynamic.ExcepInfo ByRef, UInt32, System.String)}
    _exceptionMethodString: null
    _helpURL: null
    _innerException: null
    _ipForWatsonBuckets: 0x633f1015
    _message: "Value does not fall within the expected range."
    _remoteStackIndex: 0
    _remoteStackTraceString: null
    _safeSerializationManager: {System.Runtime.Serialization.SafeSerializationManager}
    _source: "System.Dynamic"
    _stackTrace: {sbyte[96]}
    _stackTraceString: null
    _watsonBuckets: null
    _xcode: -532462766
    _xptrs: 0x00000000
    m_paramName: null
```

I first tried calling the `Add` method on the `CustomDocumentProperties` property like so:

```
workbook.CustomDocumentProperties.Add("PropertyName", "Property Value");
```

When that failed, I reviewed [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.customdocumentproperties.aspx), which remarks as follows (emphasis mine):

> This property returns the entire collection of custom document
>   properties. **Use the
>   Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperties.Item(System.Object) property**
>   to return a single member of the collection (a
>   Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperties object) **by specifying either
>   the name of the property** or the collection index (as a number).

Comment: Did you actually, literally, use `"PropertyName"` as the name of the property?

Comment: No and yes. The above code is a placeholder. When I tried with my actual values and it didn't work, I tried with `"PropertyName"` as the property name. Why?

Answer (score 1):

In Word (and presumably in Excel), if the property does not exist, you can set it with the CustomDocumentProperties.Add method. However, you need to be sure to pass a Type parameter, which in your case would be MsoDocProperties.msoPropertyTypeString.

Hope this helps.